# Using Selenium Python on Google page to click links

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

Trying to write a very simple script in Selenium Python. I am opening Google page with a search string then I am not able to locate any of the HTML element like "Images", "Maps" etc of any of the links appearing as a part of search. Though I am using Firebug. But only one thing worked and that is following

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name ("a")
for link in links:
    print ("hello")
```

What to do if I want to click on "Images" or "Maps"?
What to do if I want click on 1st, 2nd or a particular numbered link or click the link by partial text ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[starts-with(@href,"https://maps.google")]').click()
```

But please note that your browser would often redirect 'http://www.google.com' to a slightly different URL, and that the web-page it displays might be slightly different.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am very new to this..please tell me how to get/know this xpath value for maps link ? This command straight away is not working in my script.

Comment: If you're using Firefox: place the mouse indicator on the element whose Xpath you want to know, right click the mouse and choose 'Inspect Element'.

Comment: The above script might not work for you, because Google's web page appear differently on different browsers and on different locations around the world. For example, when I enter 'google.com' it redirects my browser to 'google.co.il', and I don't even have the 'Maps' link. I do, however, have 'Images' link, and after I enter a search, the web page is slightly changed, and the 'Images' link appears on a different place within the page, and with a slightly different look. Bottom line - I'm not sure if we are seeing the exact same page, so you will have to handle whatever you see on your browser

Answer (score 0):

> What to do if i want to click on images or maps?

```
Images: 
    img = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('img#myImage').click()
Maps:  
    map = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("map[for='myImage']").click()

1st, second or N link:
    link = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[n].click() -- or
    link = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div#someParent > a:nth-child(n)").click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its not working in my script. Actually, I have already fed some search string in Google and then further want to click on Maps or Images or some link. Could you plz solve it ?